# How to compare the elements of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

[It's a hackerrank problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Vgf.png)

Please click the above link to see the problem

I'm quite new (a beginner) been having a tough time with this.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
function solve(a, b) {
    var A = "";
    var B = "";

    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<b.length; j++) {
            if(a[i] > b[j]) {
                A = 1;
                B = "";
            }
            if(a[i] = b[j]) {
                A = "";
                B = "";
            }
            if(a[i] < b[j]) {
                A = "";
                B = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your current code look like? What are the things you need to execute? What specifically do you have trouble with?

Comment: If the arrays are of the same length, you can use a normal `for` loop and compare their values, if not, make sure that only elements that exist are checked against each other

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks I've taken note of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add 1 to array a and add 1 to array b whenever one is higher than the other on the same position.
Also assuming both arrays are the same length.

```
function solve(a, b) {
    var A = 0;
    var B = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] > b[i]) {
                A++; //add 1 point to a
            }
            else if(a[i] == b[i]) {
                //do nothing (this isn't needed, but I'll leave it to understanding purposes)
            }
            else if(a[i] < b[i]) {
                B++; // add 1 point to b
            }
        }
        var newArray = [A, B];
        return newArray;
    }
```

So the cleanest code, in this case, would be:

```
function solve(a, b) {
    var A = 0;
    var B = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] > b[i]) {
            A++; //add 1 point to a
        }
        else if(a[i] < b[i]) {
            B++; // add 1 point to b
        }
    }
    var newArray = [A, B];
    return newArray;
}
```

I'm also assuming you want to return this to somewhere, otherwise "A" and "B" won't be useful as they won't get out of the function ever.

Comment: what if array2 length is higher than array1 :) ?

Comment: But then, what would you wanna compare if array1 has 3 numbers and array2 has 4? The 4th comparision would be none and 4th number on array2

The problem you referenced says that both arrays length is 3.